# Why does Powershell say that System.Drawing.Point does not contain method named split.

Tags: string, powershell, split

The below code throws the below error even though the code does run and successfully does what I want it to.

> Method invocation failed because [System.Drawing.Point] does not
>   contain a method named 'Split'.

I am trying to split the following string to just extract the Y coordinates.

{X=695,Y=665}

Code is below.

```
$Y_Axis = $postTopScroll2.Split('=')[-1]     
write-host $Y_Axis # 665}

$Y_Axis2 = $postTopScroll2.Split('}')[0]     
Write-Host $Y_Axis2 # 665
```

I can't find any information on this online.

Comment: What you see is a formatted string representation of the object - use `$postTopScroll2.Y` to grab the value of the `Y` property

Comment: Because the [`System.Drawing.Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) class does not have a method named `Split`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems based off your post that $postTopScroll2 is a System.Drawing.Point
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx

Which looks like you wont need to do any split as it has already properties for X and Y

```
[System.Drawing.Point]$postTopScroll2 = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(11,99)
$Y_Axis = $postTopScroll2.y
write-output $Y_Axis
```

which returns **99**